# Circumventing QgsCredentials script called from Pre-execution?

Tags: pyqgis

I've got a stored project that, when opened is connecting to my PostgreSQL DB, and is loading several layers. All good.

I'm using a script that is called from Pre-execution (Processing/Options and configuration)
that is using the QgsCredentialDialog to distinguish between admin and regular user.

```
def LoginCredentials():
  uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
  uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "Blah", None, None)
  connInfo = uri.connectionInfo()

  (success, user, passwd) = QgsCredentialDialog.instance().get(connInfo, None, Nones)
  if success:
    uri.setPassword(passwd)
    uri.setUsername(user)
    iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Welcome!", "Welcome "+str(user), level=QgsMessageBar.INFO, duration=3)

def run_script(iface):
  LoginCredentials()
```

Issues:

- one of my 7 layers is able to be loaded before the credentials dialog pops up.

  the credentials dialog is printing a string just above the username/password textboxes with dbname, host, port, user, password and sslmode, all filled out! (I'm guessing the values are read from the .qgs project file, but I rather it didn't show it)

  if I keep hitting the Cancel button I can see that the layers are loaded one by one until everything is loaded and the credentials dialog just disappear.

I'm *very* new to QGIS (4 days), so it might be that I've overlooked something very essential.